# Where can you check your suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, profile-page

Today I submitted a few edits to people's posts and when I wanted to submit another one I wasn't able to because: "You have too many pending edits. Further edits cannot be submitted until prior edits have been approved."

My problem is that I don't even remember on what posts I suggested my edits and I don't know where to check it! Is there a way to check my edits on my profile page or in general?

Comment: For you, the link is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17033559/megamix-craft?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)

Comment: What do you want to do with them, once you find them?